# Can not start the openstack-nova-compute.service on the compute node

Tags: openstack, openstack-nova

I want to start the `openstack-nova-compute.service`:

```
systemctl restart openstack-nova-compute.service
```

there is no print information(I was think it start success, but I am wrong)

I use the below command to check the `openstack-nova-compute.service` status:

```
[root@ha-node1 ~]# systemctl status openstack-nova-compute.service
● openstack-nova-compute.service - OpenStack Nova Compute Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/openstack-nova-compute.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: activating (start) since Thu 2017-08-03 00:23:52 CST; 6s ago
 Main PID: 103174 (nova-compute)
   CGroup: /system.slice/openstack-nova-compute.service
           └─103174 /usr/bin/python2 /usr/bin/nova-compute
```

You see it is not running.

In the `/var/log/nova/nova-compute.log`:

```
...
2017-08-03 00:21:49.108 102461 WARNING nova.virt.libvirt.driver [req-867437ed-626e-499d-8928-5e673ccef7ea - - - - -] Cannot update service status on host "ha-node1" due to an unexpected exception.
2017-08-03 00:21:49.108 102461 ERROR nova.virt.libvirt.driver Traceback (most recent call last):
2017-08-03 00:21:49.108 102461 ERROR nova.virt.libvirt.driver   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nova/virt/libvirt/driver.py", line 3288, in _set_host_enabled
2017-08-03 00:21:49.108 102461 ERROR nova.virt.libvirt.driver     service = objects.Service.get_by_compute_host(ctx, CONF.host)
2017-08-03 00:21:49.108 102461 ERROR nova.virt.libvirt.driver   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oslo_versionedobjects/base.py", line 177, in wrapper
2017-08-03 00:21:49.108 102461 ERROR nova.virt.libvirt.driver     args, kwargs)
2017-08-03 00:21:49.108 102461 ERROR nova.virt.libvirt.driver   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nova/conductor/rpcapi.py", line 236, in object_class_action_versions
2017-08-03 00:21:49.108 102461 ERROR nova.virt.libvirt.driver     args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
2017-08-03 00:21:49.108 102461 ERROR nova.virt.libvirt.driver   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oslo_messaging/rpc/client.py", line 169, in call
2017-08-03 00:21:49.108 102461 ERROR nova.virt.libvirt.driver     retry=self.retry)
2017-08-03 00:21:49.108 102461 ERROR nova.virt.libvirt.driver   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oslo_messaging/transport.py", line 97, in _send
2017-08-03 00:21:49.108 102461 ERROR nova.virt.libvirt.driver     timeout=timeout, retry=retry)
2017-08-03 00:21:49.108 102461 ERROR nova.virt.libvirt.driver   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oslo_messaging/_drivers/amqpdriver.py", line 464, in send
2017-08-03 00:21:49.108 102461 ERROR nova.virt.libvirt.driver     retry=retry)
2017-08-03 00:21:49.108 102461 ERROR nova.virt.libvirt.driver   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oslo_messaging/_drivers/amqpdriver.py", line 453, in _send
2017-08-03 00:21:49.108 102461 ERROR nova.virt.libvirt.driver     result = self._waiter.wait(msg_id, timeout)
2017-08-03 00:21:49.108 102461 ERROR nova.virt.libvirt.driver   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oslo_messaging/_drivers/amqpdriver.py", line 336, in wait
2017-08-03 00:21:49.108 102461 ERROR nova.virt.libvirt.driver     message = self.waiters.get(msg_id, timeout=timeout)
2017-08-03 00:21:49.108 102461 ERROR nova.virt.libvirt.driver   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oslo_messaging/_drivers/amqpdriver.py", line 238, in get
2017-08-03 00:21:49.108 102461 ERROR nova.virt.libvirt.driver     'to message ID %s' % msg_id)
2017-08-03 00:21:49.108 102461 ERROR nova.virt.libvirt.driver MessagingTimeout: Timed out waiting for a reply to message ID 6adbf888ce9a47f9acfbcccfb48602e6
2017-08-03 00:21:49.108 102461 ERROR nova.virt.libvirt.driver
2017-08-03 00:21:49.222 102461 INFO nova.virt.libvirt.host [req-867437ed-626e-499d-8928-5e673ccef7ea - - - - -] Libvirt host capabilities <capabilities>
...
```

Comment: The logs show "Timeout". Please check if the controller and compute are NTP synced.